# d3 doesn't show the output

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My json file contains State and Sales.

My task is to sum the sales based on state in a bar chart.

I have nested the state and summed the sales.

This is my code:

```
d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {
   var data = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.State;})
  .rollup(function(d) { 
   return d3.sum(d, function(g) {return g.Sales; });
  }).entries(data);

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.State = d.key;
        d.Sales = d.Sales;
    });

  // scale the range of the data

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.State; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Sales; })]);
```

This is the error:

[image]

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: d3.v3.min.js:1 Error: <rect> attribute y: Expected length, "NaN".
o @ d3.v3.min.js:1
11d3.v3.min.js:1 Error: <rect> attribute height: Expected length, "NaN". error in console

Comment: i have attached the output as image

Comment: Stack snippet is for **running code** only. I just edited your question removing it.

Comment: What is the structure of your data? Could you provide a sample maybe?

Comment: @elakiya something wrong with your data. could you please provide sample data?

Comment: this is my data ,my task is to sum the california and display as single bar[
{
 "State": "Washington",
 "Sales": 22.18 
},
{
 "State" : "California",
 "Sales": 12.20
},
{
 "State" : "New Jersey",
 "Sales": 4700
},
{
 "State" : "Minnesota",
 "Sales": 34.89
},
{
 "State" : "New York",
 "Sales" : 3363.53

},
{
 "State" : "Montana",
 "Sales" : 1400.53

},
{
 "State" : "California",
 "Sales" : 57.07
}]

Comment: I can spot one mistake: `data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.State = d.key;
        d.Sales = d.value;//instead of d.Sales
    });` d3.nest will roll up the sum in `values` field.

Comment: i have to change it from d.Sales to d.value , but the same error occur in java script console
d3.v3.min.js:1 Error: <rect> attribute y: Expected length, "NaN".
o @ d3.v3.min.js:1
11d3.v3.min.js:1 Error: <rect> attribute height: Expected length, "NaN".
o @ d3.v3.min.js:1

Comment: i have to change from d.value to d.values its working .i have tried last 2 days.Thank you to every one